# Получение информации об оборудовании Windows

Tags: windows, ос

Разрабатываю ПО. Нужно получить информацию об подключенном физическом оборудовании(всех устройств подключенных к системной шине). Windows.

Comment: `lsusb` возвращает перечень устройств USB.

Comment: Программно получить или просто посмотреть? Если программно, то какой язык?

Comment: SetupAPI, например SetupDiGetClassDevs и перечисление потомков.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics только в винде нет lsusb, аналогичный софт не является "стандартным", и USB вряд ли можно назвать "системной шиной".

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Метку `linux` успели убрать.